# Scripts not loading in Roblox

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

**ALL I TRY DOESNT WORK**
I have a localscript in StarterGui that should create a TextButton, but it doesnt. I did a bit of research, and it turns out that the script is not loading.
Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the script is enabled from the roblox studio properties. If it is enabled something must be throwing error, in that case it should appear in the console. Try to do something simple first like typing only print("something") in the script.

Edit: To check if the script is Disabled look at the propierties window with the script selected, it should be unchecked:

[image: script propierties]

Comment: It doesn't raise an error, and when I ***DID*** put a print statement it didn't print to the console. Also please explain how to check if the script is enabled

Comment: I edited the answer with an explanation about how to check if it's disabled.